# Sort by key in Cassandra

Tags: sorting, cassandra, hector

Let's assume I have a keyspace with a column family that stores user objects and the key of these objects is the username.

How can I use Hector to get a list of users sorted by username?

I tried to use a RangeSlicesQuery, paging works fine with this query, but the results are not sorted in any way.

I'm an absolute Cassandra beginner, can anyone point me to a simple example that shows how to sort a column family by key? Please ask if you need more details on my efforts.

Edit:

The result was not sorted because I used the default RandomPartitioner instead of the OrderPreseveringPartitioner in cassandra.yaml.

Probably it's better not to rely on the sorting by key but to use a secondary index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting [Cassandra - The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449390412)

> Column names are stored in sorted order according to the value of compare_with. Rows,
>   on the other hand, are stored in an order defined by the partitioner (for example,
>   with RandomPartitioner, they are in random order, etc.)

I guess you are using `RandomPartitioner` which

> ... return data in an essentially random order.

You should probably use `OrderPreservingPartitioner (OPP)` where

> Rows are therefore stored
>   by  key  order,  aligning  the  physical  structure  of  the  data  with  your  sort  order.

Be aware of inefficiency of OPP.

---

(edit on Mar 07, 2014)
**Important:**

This answer is very old now.

It is a system-wide setting. You can set in `cassandra.yaml`. See [this doc](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/configuration/node_configuration#partitioner). Again, OPP is highly discouraged. This document is for version 1.1, and you can see *it is deprecated*. It is likely that it is removed from latest version. If you do want to use OPP, you may want to revisit the architecture the architecture.

Comment: when using OOP (OrderPreservingPartitioner) then keys are order by some PK and if I were to insert a new data into the cassandra table, does that mean it will insert the new element in the correct place or will it resort things?

Comment: how do u use it for a table OrderPreservingPartitioner?

Comment: Is it like a setting for a keyspace or a table?

Answer (score 1):

Or create a row called "meta:userNames" in same column family and put all user names as a look up hash. Something like that.

```
Users {
    key: "meta:userNames" {david:david, paolo:paolo, victor:victor},
    key: "paolo" {password:"*****", locale:"it_it"},
    key: "david" {password:"*****", locale:"en_us"},
    key: "victor" {password:"*****", locale:"en_uk"}
}
```

First query the `meta:userNames` columns (that are sorted) and use them to get the user rows. Don't try to get everything via single db query as in SQL driven databases. Use Cassandra as huge Hash Map which provides rapid random access to its data.